# Cannot install FOSUserBundle Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying to install Symfony FOSUserBundle in the PHPStorm Terminal with the following command:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~1.3"
```

The terminal throws this exception.

```
 Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/security-bundle 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2,
 v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.2.7, required as 3.2.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

for Symfony > 2.7, you have to load FOSUserBundle 2.0.

```
$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```